# Calculations In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

My order of operations are getting mixed in this (should be basic) arithmetic operation.  What I am after is to first divide, then subtract.  However, that is not what is taking place.  My desired result set (including equation) is:

> (22/44)-10 = -9.5
>   (14/11)-5 = -3.72

But What I get is

> -10.8571428571429
>   -43.9545454545455

Here is sample DDL, what must I update to get my desired result set?

```
DECLARE @blue TABLE (p1 float, p2 float, p3 float, number int)
INSERT INTO @blue VALUES 
('1', 22.00, 44.00, 10.00), ('2', 14.00, 11.00, 5.00)

Select
number,
SUM(p1/p2-p3)
FROM @blue
GROUP BY number
```

Comment: The edit changed the question substantially, making the answer obsolete. Plus, in the edited question, the inserted data did not match with the output. So I rolled back the question to its original form. If you want, you can post the corrected `INSERT` as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you aren't using the right columns. You specified (22/44)-10, which is p2/p3-number. But what your query is doing is p1/p2-p3.

So it's just a matter of fixing which column is which. I'm not sure how you want this grouped, but here you go:

```
Select
number,
SUM((p2/p3)-number)
FROM @blue
GROUP BY number
```

Maybe you want:

```
Select
p1,
SUM((p2/p3)-number)
FROM @blue
GROUP BY p1
```

You should also consider using numeric instead of float since float is just approximate.

Comment: Ah, adding the extra paren solved it.  All I needed Was SUM((p1/p2)-p3)

Comment: Maybe the extra parentheses helped your actual query, but it doesn't impact the outcome with the sample you provided. Your sample is simply using the wrong column names.

Comment: I only added the parentheses to make it clear the order of operations, but SQL already is doing it that way.

Comment: The parentheses in `(p1/p2)-p3` are redundant, as Tara explained. You were inserting data in the wrong columns.